# flexdashboard tabset renders poorly on server

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am using a tabset in my flexdashboard and it isn't coming through when I post to [shinyapps.io](https://rjake.shinyapps.io/data_explorer/)

The image on the left is how it looks locally and how I want it to look. The image on the right shows how it renders once deployed, header formatting shown, no tabs. Code for this app can be found at the top right corner where it says `</>Source Code`. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of R perhaps with different versions of packages on your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone in the RStudio community figured it out. The solutions was to use add a space in the header: `### gglplot` instead of  `###ggplot`